# Apply function across rows of zoo object in R

Tags: r, function, zoo

I would like to calculate mean for each row for this zoo object, so at the end I need to have a new zoo object with mean for each minute. 
Actually I am trying to apply more advanced statistics but from the computational point of view, it should be the same as mean.

> head(zs)

```
2014-03-09 08:00:00 1839.00 1842.00 1849.00 1838.50 1851.75 1843.50 1862.50 1874.00 1875.00 1878.00
2014-03-09 08:01:00 1838.75 1842.00 1848.75 1838.25 1851.75 1844.25 1862.50 1874.00 1875.25 1877.75
2014-03-09 08:02:00 1838.50 1842.25 1848.25 1838.25 1851.50 1843.75 1862.50 1874.00 1875.50 1878.00
2014-03-09 08:03:00 1839.25 1842.50 1848.25 1838.50 1851.50 1843.00 1862.25 1874.00 1875.50 1877.75
2014-03-09 08:04:00 1839.25 1842.50 1848.25 1838.00 1851.50 1843.00 1862.25 1874.25 1875.25 1877.75
2014-03-09 08:05:00 1838.75 1842.25 1848.25 1837.75 1851.75 1843.50 1862.25 1874.00 1875.50 1877.75
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
zoo(rowMeans(zs), time(zs))
```

or

```
zoo(apply(zs, 1, mean), time(zs))
```

or

```
Reduce(`+`, as.list(zs)) / ncol(zs)
```

or

```
zmean <- zs[, 1]
for(i in 2:ncol(zs)) zmean <- zmean + zs[, i]
zmean <- zmean / ncol(zs)
```

*ADDED* a few more approaches

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well after changing indexing of zoo zs object from `index(zs)<-as.POSIXct(index(zs), format="%H:%M:%S")` to  `index(zs)<-as.POSIXlt(index(zs), format="%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Do not use POSIXlt with zoo.  POSIXct does work.  If it seems not then you have made some other error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and wanted a more robust solution.  Specifically, I wanted a function that worked identically to `apply` except when a `zoo` object (or object that inherits from `zoo`, such as `xts`) was passed in the argument `X`.  In this case, the function should return a `zoo` (or `xts` etc.) object whenever possible.  The result should also retain any additional attributes that the user may have attached to the original `zoo` object.

There are several challenges.  First, depending on what's passed to `apply` via the arguments `MARGIN` and `FUN`, `apply` might return a `list`, a `vector`, or an `array` with dimensions greater than 2.  See the `apply` documentation for more details.

So, if you think about it, the only time result from `apply` can be returned as a `zoo` object is if the result is either a `matrix` with `nrow(result) == nrow(originalZooObject)` or a vector with `length(result) == nrow(originalZooObject)`.  Otherwise, you can't be sure how to add the `index` values of the original `zoo` object to the result from `apply`.

I came up with the following code which retains all of the applicable attributes of the original `zoo` object in the result.  Therefore, it will also work with most S3 classes built atop `zoo`, for instance, `xts`.

The only thing I am aware of that won't work well is that the user may have attached an attribute that applies to the columns of the original `zoo` object.  If `FUN` consolidates columns, then the user attribute might not be appropriate for the columns of the result.

Although I used the naming convention for dispatch from a generic function, `apply` is not a generic, so `apply.zoo` is designed to be called directly.  If one were to override the `apply` function with generic version of `apply`, then `apply.zoo` would run automatically any time a `zoo` object were passed to `apply`.

```
apply.zoo = function(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...) {
  result = apply(as.matrix(X), MARGIN, FUN, ...)
  # if result is not a list and X is a zoo object, we can try to convert result
  # to zoo.
  if(!is.list(result) | is.zoo(X)) {
    # if FUN was applied across rows and has the right length but simplfied to a
    # vector, convert result back to a matrix
    if(is.null(dim(result)) & MARGIN[1] == 1 & length(result) == nrow(X)) {
      result = matrix(result, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, "result"))
    }
    # if we don't have a matrix at this point, we can't convert back to a zoo object.
    if(is.matrix(result)) {
      # the matrix returned by apply sometimes has dates as columns and series as
      # rows.  Check for this and transpose.
      if(identical(dimnames(result)[[1]], dimnames(X)[[2]])) result = t(result)
      # if result has maintained the same number of rows, it can be restored to a
      # zoo object.
      if(identical(nrow(X), nrow(result))){
        # first ensure the dimname of rows is NULL
        dimnames(result)[1] = list(NULL)
        # then restore all attributes, other than dim and dimnames
        result = 
          do.call(
            structure, 
            c(
              list(result), 
              attributes(X)[-which(names(attributes(X)) %in% c("dim", "dimnames"))]
            )
          )

      }
    }
  }
  result
}
```